# Ways to Encode context for text classification?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, word-embeddings

I have a binary classification task which has the following specification:

**Input:** Chunk of text (not more than a few sentences, mostly a sentence).
**Additional Input:** For each input sample there is additional information available (which is also some text of similar length, max 2-3 sentences).
**Problem:** Classify text content using additional context
**Problem Type:** Binary classification

Essentially the task boils down to classifying the *content* conditioned on the *context* or **p(content|context)**.

I was thinking of effective ways to encode the text for classification using a deep neural network. I searched for recent works but the existing literature mostly use the technique mentioned below.

I was wondering if there is a better way to encode context? Which has shown to be effective in some domain as compared to just concatenation.

***Encode then concatenate***: This involves encoding the context using ways similar to the content and then concatenating the feature representation before classification. This is the widely used technique. There are a lot of variants of this technique (different ways to encode text e.g. using tfidf rep, word embedding, LSTMs, CNNs ) which are widely explored.

Are there any better ways to bring context information during classification?

P.S: Recursive RNN is something that I have on my TODO.

Comment: Why are you treating context as a different part of the input? Does a classifier using context + content concatenated not work?

Comment: Concatenating both does not make sense as my goal is to 'predict a class based on content keeping in mind the context'. There must be a better way than to just concatenate.

Comment: Concatenation does “keep in mind the context”.

Comment: But there is still a possibility that the classifier learns to predict 'label based on both content & context' is we just concatenate. Basically, i wanted the classifier to not take decisions based on full information from context

Comment: @kbrose think of a situation when we have to classify some text based on content, while keeping in mind the relationship of content with some reference text, which I am referring to as context

Answer (score 1):

A Recursive Neural Network (RNN) is best suited to solve your problem. And if you want to take a step further try [Recursive Neural Tensor Network](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf). You can generate compositions for entire sentences using RNN both for your **content** and **context** data. This will help you map your sentences to a higher dimensional space and as an output you will get numerical values (or embeddings) both for your content and context. Feeding these values into a simple logistic classifier will do your task. For a brief overview on RNNs take a look at this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24FQOQMcOIY&t=2027s) by Richard Socher.